# I am having problems installing Expo cli, it shows a lot of warnings

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I entered npm install -g expo-cli

[upper part pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv0EO.png)

[lower part pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd9Yh.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens, because nowadays when packages are installed with npm it runs command **npm audit** at the same time and informs user about possible vulnerabilities in downloaded dependency.

I attempted the same installation with node version 16.11 and OSX, the result was the same. However, these are not errors but vulnerabilities included in dependencies that Expo is using, and Expo by itself is working properly but has some vulnerabilities in it.

Therefore, there is not much that can be done from your perspective. Expo should fix these.

EDIT: And those warnings, those are a similar issue, which you cannot address. Expo is using dependencies that are old and are being deprecated.

Comment: To follow up on this answer; in [this linked github issue from their repo](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4330) a developer answers that, "Yes, this is fairly normal, as you know, npm is a tangled web of nested dependencies, there's bound to be a vulnerability somewhere in the tree. However, this is a CLI tool, that you use locally, that is not part of your actual app, so that makes it not really relevant."